# Elastic net regularization - variables penalization

Tags: feature-selection, lasso, dimensionality-reduction, regularization, elastic-net

I have a data with ~ 3000 factor predictors with ~ 6 levels, many rows (300k+), and binary Y (trying to predict probability of event). There are many groups of variables that are highly correlated. I have tried using elastic net regularization, but the results are not satisfactory (read on...). I tested grid search over alpha values with automated lambda search, both for complete set of attributes and for top N variables chosen by grid search over full dataset.

I know that using my data I can achieve gini 0.5 on validation data using 25 variables. Elastic net regularization can achieve about the same performance, but only at the expense of using much more variables (100+). I suppose this is because when weights are estimated for all factor levels separately. ENR will reach optimum solution, but with no regard to how many variables are chosen at the end (weights are penalized, not number of variables). This way I end up in a situation that for 70% variables in the selected model only 1 weight for one level of variable is estimated and used.

Is there some different flavour of ENR that would penalize number of variables in the model? Is there anything I can do to get more parsimonious model (in terms of variables, not weights)?

There are many reasons to have model with smaller number of attributes (explainability, costs of data acquisition, maintenance of model, costs of implementation)

Comment: Maybe you should try LASSO instead of elastic net? It is likely to result in fewer variables with non-zero coefficients than in the case of elastic net. But maybe that is still not satisfactory...

Comment: @RichardHardy I tried alpha varying from 0 (ridge) to 1 (lasso) using 0.05 as a step. However, this impacts number of weights estimated, not number of variables in the model.

Comment: Doesn't pure LASSO result in more zero weights than elastic net that allows for some LASSO and some ridge? It might be a peculiar dataset. However, I understand that pure LASSO is not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Variable inclusion/exclusion is associated with $L_0$ penalty. Check out Dicker et al ["Variable selection and estimation with the seamless $L_0$ penalty"](http://www.stat.rutgers.edu/home/ldicker/papers/SELO.pdf). While $L_0$ penalty is computationally expensive and becomes infeasible for a moderate number of variables, the authors propose an alternative which is efficiently implemented using a coordinate descent algorithm. It would be interesting to find out whether that can be combined with LASSO or ridge so that *both* the coefficient size *and* the number of variables would be penalized.

Comment: Also, I liked the slides by Zou ["Introduction of Penalization Methods for Variable Selection"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFgQFjAGahUKEwjitvfApaTIAhUk8HIKHR5tCgY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat-center.pku.edu.cn%2FStat%2FUploads%2FFiles%2F%5B20130718_1010%5DHuiZou_Lecture_variableselection.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEoVuyEfeOhAuXaHklWL_NJBIkPFg&sig2=7lE0HEvsk3HIMd54aKnVOw&bvm=bv.104317490,d.bGQ) where he reviews quite some advances of the last 10-20 years in regularization with LASSO, elastic net, etc.